# How can 6.10 ₿ be the average value of a Bitcoin transaction (lately)?

Tags: transactions, volume, statistics

Number of Bitcoins sent in the last 24 hours: 1.84 million ₿.
Number of Bitcoin transactions in the last 24 hours: ~301,900.

This becomes on average 6.10 ₿ per transaction. That's shocking to me. Since I just started with this little "formula", I don't know how normal/unusual this is.

It *sounds* extremely strange. I would've guessed that 0.01 ₿ or something would be the most common amount. Not multiple Bitcoins at once. Certainly not 6.10 ₿ on average.

Is this an extreme 24 hours in that sense? Or is this normal?! Or has there been some really MASSIVE single one which skews the average for today grossly?

Comment: It might be interesting to look at the median as well as the arithmetic mean.

Comment: In other assets you can manipulate price by doing big realestate trades in a region to move up the price.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal. Here you can see a chart of average transacted value every day: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/charts/average-transaction-amount-btc

There are 2 things that contribute to this:

1. The very large transactions skewing the numbers. This becomes more apparent if you take a look at the median transaction values, which are around the 0.02-0.03 BTC range, closer to your expected value: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/charts/median-transaction-amount-btc
2. The fact that many transactions aren't just sending money from one person to another person, but in most cases, includes change (sending money back to the sender's own wallet), and batched transactions (a single transaction that sends money to multiple people, often used by exchanges to process withdrawals while saving money on fees).